# getting Invalid Signature while uploading app to appstore from xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

Getting below error when uploading app to appstore from xcode.

Invalid Signature. Code object is not signed at all. The file at path “Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/drawable/extract.sh” is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose “Clean All” in Xcode, delete the “build” directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing. (ID: d25ff464-670d-4617-b383-d90a1808c491

Comment: Why are you trying to include a shell script in your bundle?

Comment: @Paulw11 By default is is coming when i tried to archive

Comment: Open your project in Xcode and use the file properties inspector to make sure the shell script isn't part of your target.